# Currency conversion JSON API parsing with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

Could anyone help me parse this JSON API with PHP? I need to retrieve the currency exchange rate.

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%3D%22eurusd%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=cbfunc

Comment: how can I get the exchange rate into a variable?

Comment: The response is JSON? Then http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to omit the last parameter in the URL, just remove `&callback=cbfunc`.

The PHP code to fetch the content is:

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("... your url ...");
$parsedData = json_decode($rawData);
```

`$parsedData` will now contain the content in a nested object structure.

#### Further info

You need fopen wrappers enabled for this to work. If they are not enabled, just use cURL to load the content from the page and put it into `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that you can use to convert a currency to another currency using the respective 3 character currency codes (i.e. "USD" to "GBP").

```
<?php

  function convertCurrencyUnit($from_Currency, $to_Currency, $unit_amount = 1) {

    $url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%3D%22' . $from_Currency . $to_Currency . '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';

    $rawdata = file_get_contents($url);
    $decodedArray = json_decode($rawdata, true);
    $converted_unit_amount = $decodedArray['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];

    return $converted_unit_amount * $unit_amount;
  }

?>
```

For example, see the following simple call of this function.

```
<?php

  echo convertCurrencyUnit("USD", "GBP");  //Prints "0.5953" to the browser. The current conversion rate from US Dollar to British Pound as of 04-16-2014.

?>
```

Also, you can pass an optional third parameter into the function to do a simple multiplication after the conversion is done.